# If there is no data in database corresponding to a value how to show them in empty array

Tags: java, collections

i am creating a json format with java collection i have successfully done it but facing a small issue 
let me explain you guys

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
            String menu = resultSet.getString("menu");
            String subMenu = resultSet.getString("submenu");
            String link = resultSet.getString("link");

            map.compute(menu, (key, subMenus) -> {
                Map<String, String> mapSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                mapSubMenu.put("type", subMenu);
                mapSubMenu.put("link", link);

                subMenus = subMenus != null ? subMenus : new ArrayList<>();
                subMenus.add(mapSubMenu);

                return subMenus;
            });
            str = gson.toJson(map);
        }
        System.out.println(str);
```

above is my code which is giving me json like this

```
    {
  "India": [
    {
      "type": "delhi",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "mumbai",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "australia": [
    {
      "type": "sydney",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "melbourn",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "spain": [
    {
      "type": "valencia",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "madrid",
      "link": "https: //www.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "Log Out": [
           {

    }
  ]
}
```

in my db there is no link and type for out let so i only want it to be like

1. "logout": []

but dont know how can i achieve that..

[This is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/512X4.png)

Comment: you want to show data that isn't there?

Comment: @Stultuske Looks like OP wants `"Log Out": [{}]` -> `"Log Out": []`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon yup i have uploaded a image of my database table please check

Comment: @Stultuske  i have updated my quetion with image link please check

Answer (score 1):

Return Empty ArrayList to get **"logout": []**

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
        String menu = resultSet.getString("menu");
        String subMenu = resultSet.getString("submenu");
        String link = resultSet.getString("link");

        map.compute(menu, (key, subMenus) -> {
            Map<String, String> mapSubMenu = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            mapSubMenu.put("type", subMenu);
            mapSubMenu.put("link", link);

            subMenus = subMenus != null ? subMenus : new ArrayList<>();

            //check for empty or null string otherwise return empty ArrayList
            if(!"".equalsIgnoreCase(subMenu) && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(link))
             subMenus.add(mapSubMenu);

            return subMenus;
        });
        str = gson.toJson(map);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: `!"".equalsIgnoreCase(s)` - for which `String s` you need to ignore the case? Why not just `!subMenu.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @LuCio It's up to you, You can use isEmpty or equals or equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: Sure, if readability and simplicity doesn't matter I can even use sth like: `new String(s.toCharArray()).length() != 1024 - Math.pow(2, 10);`

Comment: @AravindP  hey what if submenu is empty and link has some vale..i.e if one of feild have value then its giving empty only..i have tried or (||) in this case it gives me type="" and link ="somelink"  when there is data in link and not in submenu

Comment: @viveksingh Its behaviour of map to JSON convertion, If map doesn't have any values then empty { } braces will be your JSON String, otherwise it will be { "type":"", "link":"somevalue" } depends upon values. In your case your case your adding empty map to your ArrayList thats why your getting { "logout":[{}] } instead { "logout":[] }

Comment: @AravindP here i have ltype="" and link="logout" but still its showing logout[] by your answer

Comment: @viveksingh Because I have used && operator, what kind of JSON string you want for values type="" and link="logout" ?

Comment: @AravindP i have found that solution with javascript while rendering the navbar on HTML.. i have a small another question can you cleare that out for me

Comment: @viveksingh sure!

Comment: @AravindP i have only ^ reputation so not able to chat :(

Comment: @viveksingh post it as question and share it. :)

Comment: @AravindP yupp thats the only option